# cuda host_config error: #endif without #if

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, cuda, amazon-ec2

After installing **cuda-8.0** on an ec2-gxl2 instance, I am trying to validate installation by running NVIDIA_CUDA-8.0_Samples and get an **host_config** related error:

```
$ cd ~/NVIDIA_CUDA-8.0_Samples/1_Utilities/deviceQuery
$ make
```

I get:

```
In file included from /usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin/..//include/cuda_runtime.h:78:0,
                 from deviceQuery.cpp:19:
/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin/..//include/host_config.h:260:2: error: #endif without #if
 #endif /* !__HOST_CONFIG_H__ */
  ^
Makefile:250: recipe for target 'deviceQuery.o' failed
make: *** [deviceQuery.o] Error 1
```

Anyone here has ever encountered this issue?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you really just want to know if anyone here has encountered this issue?

Comment: A solution would be nice.